# Better understanding of Dependency Injection - Resolving New Instances?

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I have been working a job that requires me to focus on Dependency Injection.  For posterity, I am using this in Swift/SwiftUI, though I believe my lack of understanding is more inherent in the concept than the language.

I have created a Dependency Injection container, which can be used to register and resolve types and components.  As such;

```
protocol MyContainerProtocol {
    func register<Component>(type: Component.Type, component: Any)
    func resolve<Component>(type: Component.Type) -> Component?
}

final class MyContainer: MyContainerProtocol {
    
    static let shared = DependencyContainer()
    private init() { }
    
    var components: [String: Any] = [:]
    
    func register<Component>(type: Component.Type, component: Any) {
        components["\(type)"] = component
    }
    
    func resolve<Component>(type: Component.Type) -> Component? {
        return components["\(type)"] as? Component
    }
}
```

This will become relevant below, but I have a class in my project, named `VideoProcessor`;

```
class VideoProcessor: SomeProtocol {
    var codec: String
    var format: String

    init(codec: String, format: String) {
      self.codec = codec
      self.format = format
    }
}
```

Early on in the app's lifecycle, I am registering the component.  For example;

```
let container = DependencyContainer.shared
container.register(type: VideoProcessor.self, component: VideoProcessor(codec: "H264", format: "MP4"))
...
let processor = container.resolve(type: VideoProcessor.self)!
```

**My Confusion:**  What is being asked of me is to resolve an instance of a type, without having to construct it when registering.  Effectively, I'm being asked to resolve a new instance of a registered type each time it is resolved.  In my mind, this means my code would resemble something like;

```
let container = DependencyContainer.shared
container.register(type: VideoProcessor.self)
...
let processorA = container.resolve(type: VideoProcessor.self)!
processorA.codec = "H264"
processorA.format = "MP4"

let processorB = container.resolve(type: VideoProcessor.self)!
processorB.codec = "H265"
processorB.format = "MOV"
```

However, `VideoProcessor` has its own dependencies, leading me to be unsure how I would register a type.

I'm unsure if my issue exists in the way my Dependency Container is built, the way my classes are built, or if the question of what's being asked of me I'm just not understanding.  Even looking at popular Swift libraries like [Swinject](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject) or [DIP](https://github.com/AliSoftware/Dip), I don't entirely see what my Container is doing improperly (or if this is where the Factory method comes in).

Comment: If you need to create a new instance each time, you could register a `(DependencyContainer) -> Component` function instead of an already constructed object. The dependency container part is there so you can resolve any dependencies you have already registered. Is it absolutely necessary that you build this from scratch instead of using a library? I've never personally used Swinject or DIP, but they've probably solved a lot of problems you're having or are going to have building it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Steven0351.  If I follow your comment, you’re advising to create a new function within my Dependency Container that, when called, returns a newly instantiated instance of a given class?  That sounds simple in practice, but per my example of VideoProcessor, how would I handle returning an instance when that instance has dependencies (rather, variables) on its own?  Could you provide a sample?

Comment: I posted an answer so I could provide a more detailed example than i can in the comments.

Comment: Thank you, @Steven0351!  I am reviewing your answer and working to digest the knowledge and give this a try.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to add an extra register function.

```swift
protocol MyContainerProtocol {
  func register<Component>(type: Component.Type, component: Any)
  func register<Component>(type: Component.Type, builder: @escaping (MyContainerProtocol) -> Component)
  func resolve<Component>(type: Component.Type) -> Component?
}

final class MyContainer: MyContainerProtocol {
  
  static let shared = MyContainer()
  private init() { }
  
  var components: [String: Any] = [:]
  
  func register<Component>(type: Component.Type, component: Any) {
    components["\(type)"] = component
  }
  
  func register<Component>(type: Component.Type, builder: @escaping (MyContainerProtocol) -> Component) {
    components["\(type)"] = builder
  }
  
  func resolve<Component>(type: Component.Type) -> Component? {
    if let singleton = components["\(type)"] as? Component {
      return singleton
    }
    
    if let builder = components["\(type)"] as? (MyContainerProtocol) -> Component {
      return builder(self)
    }
    
    return nil
  }
}
```

Then it would look like this at the call site:

```swift
struct Animal {
  let type: String
  let id = UUID()
}

struct Person {
  let name: String
  let pet: Animal
  let id = UUID()
}

class ComplicatedNetworkStack {
  let id = UUID()
  /// so much stuff in here
}

MyContainer.shared.register(type: Animal.self) { _ in Animal(type: "Dog") }
MyContainer.shared.register(type: Person.self) { container in
  Person(
    name: "Joe Dirt",
    pet: container.resolve(type: Animal.self)!
  )
}

MyContainer.shared.register(type: ComplicatedNetworkStack.self, component: ComplicatedNetworkStack())
```

If you were to run that code in a playground and resolve `Person` and `Animal` a few times, you'll see the UUID's are all different, while `ComplicatedNetworkStack`'s id is the same.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Steven0351.  If you’re willing to answer, I’m a bit curious as to the “why” and “how.”  I can’t really fathom *why* anyone would want this implementation, as I can’t help but think that the principle of dependency injection is to provide a single source of truth, not allow for creating multiple truths of the same type.  Additionally, I’m not sure *how* this varies from my example, in principle, as I could add a `let id=UUID()` to my `VideoProcessor` class, and it seems like it would do the same thing?

Comment: The `let id = UUID()` was just a bit of code to illustrate what is getting created new each time and what is being passed as an already constructed object. Personally, I don’t use dependency injection in iOS applications. All my experience with it comes through Java and Kotlin on the server side where dependency injection is a common pattern. However, I only used dependency injection for things that were performing things like database calls, outbound http requests, etc. When you go to test those objects, you can just inject mocks into your shared container instead

Comment: Thank you, @Steven0351.  I feel the same; I've not used dependency injection in iOS very heavily, especially with the advent in SwiftUI which handles such concepts using environment objects, rather than needing a container.  This was a great way to re-affirm my knowledge, and I appreciate your sample and detail.